# Trying to download ipykernel onto my virtual environment (Windows)

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook, virtualenv

I am trying to install `ipykernel` onto my virtual venv enrioment on windows. I typed `python -m pip install ipykernel` but I get the following error:

> ERROR: Could not build wheels for psutil, pyzmq, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

[image]

I tried downgrading using the command `pip install pip==21.3.1` but I did not find any luck downloading pip onto my venv afterward either. I also tried using the command `python -m pip install ipykernel` which also did not work.

Let me know if you have any other ideas!

Answer (score 0):

Try installing from source

```py
git clone
cd ipykernel
pip install -e ".[test]"
```

Comment: git clone creates the following message: "fatal: You must specify a repository to clone."

Comment: when using git clone add the url for the source repo: `git clone git@github.com:ipython/ipykernel.git`

Comment: I was able to do the first two commands using the URL for the source repo; however, the third command ''pip install -e ".[test]"'' returned an error: '''ERROR: File "setup.py" or "setup.cfg" not found. Directory cannot be installed in editable mode: C:\Users\Micha\OneDrive\Desktop\TensorFlow Object Detection\TFODCourse\tfold\bin\ipykernel (A "pyproject.toml" file was found, but editable mode currently requires a setuptools-based build.)'''

Comment: The error message to build pyzmq indicates to specify the platform with --plat-name. Try installing that dependency manually.
Another alternative is to use pip install ipykernel -U --force-reinstall to reinstall all dependencies.